# Why doesn't F# interactive flag this error?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, f#, f#-interactive

I have some code with a few hundred lines. Many small pieces of it have the following structure:

```
let soa =
    election
    |> Series.observations
printfn "%A" <| soa
```

Frequently two things happen:

1) Mysteriously the last line is changed to:

```
printfn "%A" <|
```

so that the code above and what follows becomes

```
let soa =
    election
    |> Series.observations
printfn "%A" <|

let sls =
    election
    |> Series.sample (seq ["Party A"; "Party R"])
printfn "%A" <| sls
```

This happens hundreds of lines above where I am editing the file in the editor.

2) When this happens `F# Interactive` does not flag the error. No error messages are generated. However, if I try to access `sls` I get the message:

`error FS0039: The value or constructor 'sls' is not defined.`

Any ideas on why a bit of code is erased in the editor? (This happens quite frequently)

And why doesn't `F# Interactive` issue an error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second `let` block is interpreted as argument for the preceding `printfn`, because the pipe, being an operator, provides an exception to the offset rule: the second argument of an operator does not have to be indented farther than the first argument. And since the second `let` block is not at top level, but rather is part of the `printfn`'s argument, its definitions don't become accessible outside.

Let's try some experimentation:

```
let f x = x+1

// Normal application
f 5  

// Complex expression as argument
f (5+6)

// Let-expression as argument
f (let x = 5 in x + 6)

// Replacing the `in` with a newline
f ( let x = 5
    x + 6 )

// Replacing parentheses with pipe
f <| 
  let x = 5
  x + 6

// Operators (of which the pipe is one) have an exception to the offset rule.
// This is done to support flows like this:
[1;2;3] |>
List.map ((+) 1) |>
List.toArray

// Applying this exception to the `f` + `let` expression:
f <|
let x = 5
x + 6
```